# You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: salesforce, apex

Today I have overserved one thing which I would like to share and wants to know more about it. I am doing one callout.Use case as below.

When a case gets created, in before insert trigger I am updating one field lets say F1 values as "SF".In WF if F1 = SF then mail goes to the address(generated from email service) and in the class of email service callout is done. With in the class, I am catching the exception and inserting in one custom object.Like below

```
Public class {
    public void mehod() {
        try{
            response = http.send(request);
        }
        catch(Exception error) {
            system.debug('--error--'+error);
            ExceptionClass.logException(Exception error);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I am getting Error "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out." and Callout stats code is 200 means call was successful.

But when I commented out catch block its works fine. As per my understanding if there is an exception then catch will execute and we must get above (as we can't do DMLL with Callout) error.
Fiends please share your thoughts on this thanks for reading and responding to my post.

Comment: You can't make callouts from a trigger at all. Is this executing in an `@future` method or other async context?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware that you cannot make callouts directly from a trigger.
So please create a new function for making the callout and use @future(callout=true) annotation for that function.

here is the link of KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE please refer it for your reference
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&type=1&mode=1

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, however, I decided to update the account before the callout, as I needed to concatenate some values, I followed this strategy, below is a simple example:

```
public static void updateAccount(Id recordId, String City, String PostalCode, String Country, String Street, String State_Province, String AddressType, String Complement, String Neighborhood, String Number_Address){
    
    String Number_Address_nm = Number_Address.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');
    String PostalCode_nm = PostalCode.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');
    String acId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id =: recordId LIMIT 1].Id;  
    
    Account ct = new Account();
    ct.Id = acId;
    ct.BillingCity = City;
    ct.BillingCountry = Country;
    ct.BillingPostalCode = PostalCode_nm;
    ct.BillingState = State_Province;
    ct.BillingStreet = AddressType + ' ' + Street + '   Nº: ' + Number_Address_nm + '  ' + Complement + '   BAIRRO: ' + Neighborhood ;
    update ct;      
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void Call_API(Id recordId, String City, String PostalCode, String Country, String Street, String State_Province, String AddressType, String Complement, String Neighborhood, String Number_Address){        
        ChangeAddressAPI.CallChangeAddressAPI(recordId, City, PostalCode, Country, Street, State_Province, AddressType, Complement, Neighborhood, Number_Address); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- If you call that method in a trigger: You can't.
- If you have some DML (insert/update) some record before callout: You can't.

-> Let using @future instead